# How to improve the getting of a derivative by the chain method with wx maxima?

Tags: maxima

if we want derivate by the chain rule this equation:

y=(4*x²-2*x+5)³

we have:

dy/dx = dy/du * du/dx

dy/du = 3*(4*x²-2*x+5)²

du/dx = 8*x-2

dy/du = 3*(8*x-2)*(4*x²-2*x+5)²

then I run this code in wxmaxima (17.10.1, fedora 28)

```
(%i51)  f(x):=(4*x²-2*x+5)³;
(%o51)  f(x):=(4*x^2-2*x+5)^3
(%i52)  depends(f(x),[y,u],[y,u],x);
depends: argument must be a symbol; found: (4*x^2-2*x+5)^3
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
(%i53)  diff(f(x),x);
(%o53)  3*(8*x-2)*(4*x^2-2*x+5)^2
```

already get the correct answer but want to understand why the notification: "depends: argument must be a symbol; found: (4*x^2-2*x+5)^3".

Can someone tell me how to get a "clean free problem" answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the help for `depends()` and looked at the examples?

Comment: `depends` is unnecessary here; just `f(x) := ...` and `diff(f(x), x)` are enough.